# Using labels in javascript

Tags: javascript

Can you explain to me how to use labels on statements that interact with break: switch, while, do, and for.

with example please.

Comment: What specific problem are you having? Can you show some code you don't understand?

Comment: What is the question? What are you having trouble with?

Comment: I've never, ever, ever needed to use a label in JS programming.

Comment: see:  https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/label

Comment: Ohhhhh, I never knew those existed in JS. It's like a `goto` statement. Don't use them.

Comment: down votes are a bit harsh - it may not be a well written question, and labels might well be next only to `eval` in evilness, but there's no harm in him asking.

Comment: Actually, it's not a problem. i bumped into this problem while examining javascript abilities (bumped onto it on the web). it just that you must  be carefull to use labels in javascript. i had no idea of what's it. moreover googling didn't help.

So Thank You so much, all of you, for explaining this question.
And sorry for not clear question.

Answer (score 10):

Commonly, I see it in [breaking out to outer loops](http://jsfiddle.net/HHpPR/):

```
var i, j;

dance: for (i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
    for (j = 0; j < 20; j++) {
        console.log(i+'-'+j);
        if (j === 10) { //normally, break only breaks the immediate loop
            break dance; //this one breaks the loop labelled as dance
        }
    }
}​

//continue here after i = 0,j = 10
```

Comment: a "case label" and a break/continue label are _very_ different things.

Answer (score 1):

Quouting the Mozilla Developer Network  [Language Reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/label):

> Provides a statement with an identifier that you can refer to using a break or continue statement.
>
> For example, you can use a label to identify a loop, and then use the break or continue statements to indicate whether a program should interrupt the loop or continue its execution.

Note that they also say:

> Labels are not very commonly used in JavaScript since they make programs harder to read an understand. As much as possible, avoid using labels and, depending on the cases, prefer calling functions or throwing an error

Comment: This does not answer the question. Besides, why would break <label>; be more unclear than break; ? The problem is with break, not labels.

Comment: @SamuelRossille I'm just quoting the guys that developed the language in the first place - and note that the same page _does_ describe how to use it, and hence does answer the question.

Comment: I don't use them myself, but it always seems to me there is a circularity in this argument, since in many cases the only reason they would make code "harder to read" would be because people don't use them and miss the point when looking at the code. In which case, this could be said of any language feature: using it will make the code harder to read for people who don't use or understand the feature.  This has just become a form of liturgy over time ("repeat after me...").

Comment: @goldilocks a _competent_ programmer would indeed have no problem with this concept.  However a competent programmer wouldn't need to ask in the first place...

Answer (score 1):

Here's a good [article](http://blog.stchur.com/2007/03/09/the-javascript-goto-statement/) on the GOTO label in JS.  I don't ever use GOTO label logic, so I actually learned something new today as well.

JS code from the article:

```
var pastures = getPastures();
 var i, pastureLen = pastures.length;

pastureLoop:
 for (i = 0; i < pastureLen; i++)
 {
    var pasture = pastures[i];
    var cows = pasture.getCows();

   var j, numCows = cows.length;
    for (j = 0; j < numCows; j++)
    {
       var cow = cows[j];
       if (cow.isEating())
          { continue pastureLoop; }
    }

   // No cows were eating, so fire the callback for pasture[i]
    pasture.executeCallback();    // or whatever
 }
```

Comment: The article link is broken

Answer (score 0):

Do not use labels.

Example:

```
// no label
while (condition) {
    // do something
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`label:` (`labelled statement`) basically used with break or continue statements which helps to either break or continue the labelled statement unlike normal `break` statement which only breaks the immediate loop.

Let me explain with a demo for both `break` and `continue`.

Break **:**

```js
let i, j;

loop1:
for (i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
  loop2:
  for (j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
    if (i === 1 && j === 1) {
        break loop1; // terminate the whole loop labelled as loop1 unline normal break which will only terminate the current loop)
    }
    console.log('i = ' + i + ', j = ' + j);
  }
}
```

Continue **:**

```js
let str = '';

loop1:
for (let i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
  if (i === 1) {
    continue loop1; // This statement will again run the loop labelled as loop1
  }
  str = str + i;
}

console.log(str); // '0234'
```